# how to add 2d video instead of 3d model in mind-ar by using its scripts?

Tags: javascript, aframe, gltf, 3d-model, mindar

I just started using mind-ar opensource project on git hub[text](https://github.com/hiukim/mind-ar-js?ref=mindar.org) this one has the JS version. and I cant replace the 3d model, here is the snippet

```
      <a-assets>
        <a-asset-item id="bearModel" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/hiukim/mind-ar-js@1.2.5/examples/image-tracking/assets/band-example/bear/scene.gltf"></a-asset-item>
        <a-asset-item id="raccoonModel" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/hiukim/mind-ar-js@1.2.5/examples/image-tracking/assets/band-example/raccoon/scene.gltf"></a-asset-item>
      </a-assets>
```

it is using .gltf format for its 3d models so I gave it from my local storage :file:///d:/file.gltf
but it didn't work so I deployed that file on GitHub pages and pasted that URL in it and it started loading and when I showed the target image it removed the UI mean it has placed the model on top of it but it was not showing the model. so I want to replace that model with a 2d transparent video (after removing its green screen.)

Comment: Play around with the [chromakey component](https://github.com/nikolaiwarner/aframe-chromakey-material) in pure aframe, without mindar. Once you get it done, use the same code in mindar. Any issue pops up, let us know.

Comment: hi ,@PiotrAdamMilewski thanks for suggesting , it is working correctly because of your help. if you want you can write answer for that so that the question can be closed .